# Is it possible to send PHP mails without having to make changes in php.ini file?

Tags: php

In localhost(XAMPP), I make changes in php.ini file to be able to send e-mail. But in production server, is there a way to send mails directly, without having to change my configuration file (php.ini)?

Comment: Have you already examined http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/ and http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime yet?

Comment: Most webservers have a mail server installed so you shouldn't need to configure an SMTP server if you do not want to. This is usually just required for installations on local computers since they typically do not have a mail server installed by default.

Comment: You can establish a transport connection via TCP-socket with the server and communicate with them used SMTP-protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send out emails you will need a mail server somewhere. So, you can write another PHP script that is hosted on a server with Mail/SMTP configured and make a POST/GET calls. Basically forward all your mail related queries to that server.

FYI, it is better to configure a Mail server and enable SMTP in all your PHP environments! This way all your scripts remain consistent in terms of SMTP.